# Use _id field to fill another elasticsearch 6

Tags: php, database, elasticsearch, field

lets suppose my mapping is

```
"try_field": {
    "type": "keyword"
}
```

so when i insert into this index i want try_field to have auto-generated _id value (generated by elasticsearch itself) in it.
is it posible to make it? any other solutions apart of insert then update?

I tried to do scripting but when i ran it, didn't gave me a clue.
i also thought using elasticsearch-php would help because is really flexible when talking about management and using the database as an object but stills useless in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can suggest you alternative solution:

generate id yourself and put it for _id and custom field

```
POST my_index/my_time/some_custom_id_Udl0f4E
{
  try_field: "some_custom_id_Udl0f4E"
}
```

Custom id also supported in bulk requests.

Comment: i suggested that too, but it's not a colective solution. i think i'm going to do that, thanks for the suggestion.